# Why FFMPEG PNG image compression output file bigger than input file?

Tags: ffmpeg

I have tested following ffmpeg against several images following code for compression.

```
C:\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg -y -i .\ff.png .\ff_out.png
```

for jpg images its reduces the file size but for some png images it gives output file larger than input file. i got smaller output file only for image which bit depth = 8.

Comment: Try with `ffmpeg -y -i .\ff.png -pred mixed .\ff_out.png`

Comment: ffmpeg -y -i .\ff.png -pred mixed .\ff_out.png is working for most of the PNG images

Comment: @Mulvya  If you can explain what is the meaning of " -pred " and "mixed" options is really helpful

Comment: @Mulvya ur code does not work for transparent PNG images. output is larger than input.

Comment: It depends on the input. You can add `-compression_level 9` for  maximum bitstream compression.

Comment: is compression level maximum by default in FFMPEG ?

Comment: No. It's unset i.e. encoders will default to *their* default compression level.

Answer (score 8):

The PNG specification allows for filtering the bytestream to allow for greater compression. See http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/book/chapter09.html for a description.

FFmpeg's PNG encoder defaults to no filtering. By adding `-pred mixed`, FFmpeg will apply all filtering algorithms and select the one which produces the best compression.

Comment: according to ur link it says "  PNG's two-dimensional interlacing scheme can have a significant negative impact on compression " . I run 'ffmpeg -y -i .\ff.png -compression_level 9 -pred mixed .\ff_out.png' , for some image it gives larger output file size than input file. But i run  'C:\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg -y -i .\ff.png .\ff_out.png' it gives compressed smaller file size for the same input file.

Comment: That applies to interlaced output. By default, that is off. Add `-flags +ildct` to turn it on and check. I'll just point out this statement: *For grayscale and truecolor images of 8 or more bits per sample, with or without alpha channels, dynamic filtering is almost always beneficial.* So, not 100% of the time but usually.

Comment: i found two codes that work for png images. 'ffmpeg -y -i .\wall.png -vframes 1 -r 1 -compression_level 9 -flags -ildct .\wall_out.png ' and ' ffmpeg -y -i .\alpha2.png -vframes 1 -r 1 -deinterlace -compression_level 9 -flags -ildct -pred mixed .\alpha2_out.png ' .. but i need one code that work